# How would one get a UTF-8/Unicode string from GetOpenFileName?

Tags: c++, getopenfilename, comdlg32

I'm developing an application in MinGW/C++ that uses Windows' common dialogs. The need has arisen to collect a file name that might have non-ASCII characters in it. Is there a flag or another option for retrieving a file name in Unicode, or preferably UTF-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call GetOpenFileNameW. You can do this without converting your entire app to Unicode which may be the most expedient solution.

Windows API comes in 2 flavours, ANSI and Unicode. The former has functions with an A suffix. The latter have a W suffix. You are currently using the former.

Comment: I.e. `GetOpenFileName` is really a macro, and expands to `GetOpenFileNameA` by default.